# Private app android and apple

Tags: android, ios, deployment, private

I need your help, my client wants a small downloadable App for its members and he doesn't want the application appear in the Play Store and App Store but downloaded by clicking a link on his website or in email.
How can I do this?
Which license should I take?

Thank you!

Comment: you can put in on the play store as a closed beta, only the people who have been given permission can view it on the play store, to everyone else it is completely invisible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build a release APK and place it to a specific server so the clients can download it from that link. You do not need anything. Only downside the users will get the warning that the APK is not for Google Play and might be dangerous but this is what your client wants anyway.

Comment: Also, you can't do it for iOS

Comment: You actually CAN do this with iOS using Enterprise distribution. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps.html

Comment: Thanks @72A12F4E. We are limited by the number of users? My client thinks that there are approximately 1000-2000 iOS users

Comment: No ideas for the maximum number of users?